# MariaDB : IN condition in a subquery to a view with count

Tags: mysql, view, subquery, cluster-computing, mariadb

I'm using a SQL query with a subquery with a count and a IN condition :

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 USING (field1)
WHERE table2.field2 > NOW()
AND (
    SELECT count(*) FROM view
    WHERE view.field3 = table1.field3
    AND view.field4 IN (1,7,12,18)
) <> table1.field6
```

Everything was working fine until I replace the `view` table to a VIEW.
Now I get all lines from `table1 join table2` that match `table2.field2 > NOW()`. The second condition seems to always validate.

I have to replace the IN condition with a OR to make it work

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 USING (field1)
WHERE table2.field2 > NOW()
AND (
    SELECT count(*) FROM view
    WHERE view.field3 = table1.field3
    AND (view.field4 = 1 OR view.field4 = 7 OR view.field4 = 12 OR view.field4 = 18)
) <> table1.field6
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Is it a MariaDB bug ? Is there any solutions ?

Thank you very much

**Edit**

This is the `EXPLAIN SELECT` (they are exactly the same for both query) :

```
id  select_type        table  type   possible_keys         key     key_len ref                   rows Extra
1   PRIMARY            table2 range  PRIMARY,field2        field2  8       NULL                  1927 Using index condition
1   PRIMARY            table1 ref    PRIMARY               PRIMARY 4       bddname.table2.field1 1    Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY table3 ref    PRIMARY,field3,field4 field3  4       bddname.table1.field3 72   Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY table4 eq_ref PRIMARY               PRIMARY 4       bddname.table3.field5 1    Using index
```

And this is the `CREATE VIEW` :

```sql
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`****`@`******` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view`
AS SELECT
`table4`.`field5` AS `field5`,
`table3`.`field3` AS `field3`,
`table3`.`field4` AS `field4`,
--... some other fields
FROM (`table4` join `table3` on((`table4`.`field5` = `table3`.`field5`)))
```

The MariaDB server is a cluster of 4 servers.

Comment: What are you trying to do in your own words?

Comment: The statements `coms.type in (4, 6)` and `(coms.type = 4 OR coms.type = 6)` should be identical as far as determining the rows for the result set.  Something else would seem to be the problem.  For instance, your view may introduce other logic that changes the numbers.

Comment: Let's see `EXPLAIN SELECT ..;` for both of them.  Plus `SHOW CREATE VIEW`

Comment: @juergend i want to make a fusion of two table. As a transition process i'm using a view witch can be used the same way as the future table.